# trying to get a reference to an object that is the model in an Ember route without using ember data

Tags: ember.js

I am evaluating EmberJs for a project and working through the ember screencast by Tom Dale. But I'm not using Ember Data and am trying to adjust for our content (a Post object in this example).

In the Ember Data model, he uses this.get('store').commit() to save and persist to the server. I am trying to get a save object on my Post model and call it when the user clicks the button which should fire the `save` method. How would I do this? What I have tried is at the bottom (this.save, this.model.save, this.post.save) but have included pretty much all of the code.  Also, is this general approach reasonable?

thx for help

```
window.Hex = Ember.Application.create();

Hex.Router.map(function() {
    this.resource('posts', function(){
        this.resource('post', { path: ':post_id' });
    });
});

// the model class
Hex.Post = Ember.Object.extend({
    save: function(){ a
        console.log("you clicked save");
    }

});


Hex.PostRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(params) {
      return $.getJSON("/arc/v1/api/all-post", function(data){
        var post = Hex.Post.create();
        post.set('id', data.id);
        return post;
      });
    }
});

Hex.PostController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    isEditing: false,
   actions:{
    edit: function() {
        this.set('isEditing', true);
        console.log("within edit");
    },

    doneEditing: function() {
        this.set('isEditing', false);
        this.save();  // doesn't work  trying to get a reference to the post object
        this.model.save();  // doesn't work - undefined
        this.post.save(); // doesn't work - undefined
        //this.get('store').commit(); what is called in the sample app
    }
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We at work are using Ember without EmberData. We normally put any request related logic inside the models following the ActiveRecord pattern. So the model hook inside our routes usually looks something like this:

```
Hex.PostRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
   model: function(params) {
     return Post.find(params); // returns a promise
   }
});
```

Your problem is very simple. Inside your controller you can access the model with the `content` property, so you'd have to use something like this:

```
this.get('content').save();
```

I think it's a good idea the save method returns a promise as well.
Hope it helps!

Comment: thx, I don't have so much experience with promises - looks like jQuery chaining of Rails chaining of methods. I did notice that it doesn't even look like the model object in PostController ObjectController is called and is instead generated automagically from the PostsController ArrayController. I will have to look into this more.

Comment: I've asked a separate question about class methods and Ember here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20586434/in-ember-how-to-create-a-class-method-on-ember-object-extend-that-can-work-to-ac to help understand this

Comment: To make the most of the router, definitely take some time to learn and experiment with promises.