# in ember how to create a class method on Ember.Object.extend that can work to access a json service

Tags: ember.js

Sorry to ask such a simple question but I'm looking at migrating from jQuery to Ember and am trying to figure out calling / responding json without using ember-data. One question I have is how do people suggest having class methods. Say for example I have a post object like this:

```
Hex.Post = Ember.Object.extend({
  id: null,
  body: null
});
```

Would a reasonable findById look like this?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  Hex.Post.findById=function(id){
    console.log("you are here");
    $.getJSON("/arc/v1/api/post/" + id, function(data){
         var post = Hex.Post.create();
         post.set('id', data.id);
         post.set('body',data.body);
        return post;
    });
  };
});
```

Or is this just wrong for creating a findById class method?

When I run this from the chrome console, it comes back as undefined even though the JSON call works fine in a brower. What am I doing wrong?

thx

FROM CHROME CONSOLE:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd want to define it on the class, and return the ajax call, which is then a promise

```
Hex.Post = Ember.Object.extend({
   id: null,
   body: null
});

Hex.Post.reopenClass({
   findById: function(id) {
     return Ember.$.getJSON("/arc/v1/api/post/" + id).then(function(data){
       var post = Hex.Post.create();
       post.set('id', data.id);
       post.set('body',data.body);
       return post;
     });
   }
 });
```

**Using the promise**

**from a model hook, Ember will resolve the promise for you, example below**

```
Hex.PostRoute = Em.Route.extend({
  model: function(param){
    return Hex.Post.findById(param.id);
  }
});
```

**as the promise**

```
Hex.Post.findById(42).then(function(record){
  console.log(record);
});
```

or

```
var promise = Hex.Post.findById(42);

promise.then(function(record){
  console.log(record);
});
```

And here's a simple example:

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/21/edit

[image: console]

Comment: thx for excellent answer. One quick question though, I am trying to test this via Chrome Console (which I think would be the last way of calling) and it is coming back as undefined (see above screenshot). Is this  something I am just not getting about what a promose is? Do I have a reference to a promise and need to convert it to a Post object?

Comment: Since it's an async call the promise is necessary, the function passed into `then` is called when the promise is resolved.  The promise is never converted into the result of the promise though, so you need to access it through the then, or make a reference to an external var through the then

Comment: It's important to note this wouldn't print out if run synchronously in code.

Comment: What a thorough answer! Thank you for the multiple examples.